# Symfony - Undefined index of foreign property of a manyToOne relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping, entitymanager

The case is a little bit intricate. I have a Controller action `editCreateFirstFormPart` which handles some fields of a `Workflow` object and renders an appropriate first part of a two parted form.

If I call the route of this action method with an id of a stored object the form will load all fields like it should. I store the object of the database, which fills the form, in the current session in case the user decides to cancel the editing in the second form:

```
// Persist all changes of made in the first form part
$manager->persist($workflow);
$manager->flush();

// In case the wolkflow already exists store it in the session
if(!$newWorkflow) $this->get('session')->set($workflowSessionName, $workflowBeforeSubmit);
return $this->redirectToRoute('pec_test_pra_edit_workflow_second_part', array(
    'project'               => $project->getId(),
    'workflow'              => $workflow->getId(),
    'newWorkflow'           => $newWorkflow,

    // Pass the name in the session of the stored workflow to the action method which handles the second form
    'workflowSessionName'   => $workflowSessionName,
));
```

This works like a charm. Now in case (which I retrieve) the user submits the second form via a `cancel` button I want to reset the object stored in database to the status BEFORE the first form part got submitted. Therefore I fetch the object stored in the session and want to `persist` it:

```
if($sessionObject instanceof Workflow) {
     $manager = $this->getObjectManager();
     $sessionObject = $session->get($workflowSessionName);
     $manager->persist($sessionObject);
     $manager->flush();
}
```

And here I get the following error:

> **Notice: Undefined index: 0000000061675b3d0000000022ddb0a6** in vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php (line 2917) 
> Line 2917: `return $this->entityIdentifiers[spl_object_hash($entity)];`
>
> UnitOfWork->getEntityIdentifier(*object*(Fuel))// gets called after prepareUpdateData
>
> BasicEntityPersister->prepareUpdateData(*object*(MProject))

My entity `Workflow` has an unidirectional *manyToOne* relation to a `Project` class. The `MProject` class extends `Project` and has one `fuel` property of class `Fuel`.

So **one `Fuel` has many `MProject`s** (*oneToMany*) and **Many `MProject`s have one `Fuel`** (*manyToOne*). Here are the according parts of the `.orm.yml` files:

`Fuel.orm.yml`:

```
  'ABundle\Entity\Fuel':
      ...
      oneToMany:
        projects:
          targetEntity: 'ABundle\Entity\MProject'
          mappedBy: fuel
```

Inside `Fuel` class:

```
class Fuel {

    /**
     * The collection of projects using the fuel.
     *
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
     private $projects;

     ...

}
```

`MProject.orm.yml`:

```
'ABundle\Entity\MProject':
    repositoryClass: 'ABundle\Repository\MProjectRepository'
    type:  entity

    manyToOne:
      fuel:
        targetEntity: 'ABundle\Entity\Fuel'
        inversedBy: projects
```

Inside `MProject` class:

```
use BBundle\Entity\Project as BaseProject; // Origin of Project in my Entity

class MProject extends BaseProject implements SearchableTypeAlias {

    /**
     * The fuel used by the project.
     *
     * @var Fuel
     */
    protected $fuel;
    
    ...

}
```

`Workflow.orm.yml`:

```
MyBundle\Entity\Workflow:
  ...
  manyToOne:
    project:
      targetEntity: BBundle\Entity\Project
      cascade: [persist]
  ...
```

Inside `Workflow` class:

```
use BBundle\Entity\Project;

class Workflow  {

    /**
     * @var Project
     */
    private $project;

    ...

}
```

---

I don´t really know whats wrong in my usecase especially because there is no problem storing the `$workflow` object with calling `persist` in the first Controller action method.

### How can I fix this **Undefined index** error?

Comment: make sure you have only yml files for entities. Make sure you got right syntax => note `quotes`
```cascade: ["persist"]```

yml-files always cached! Do clear-cache as well for dev as for prod environment.

Comment: @V-Light Thanks for your suggestion. You were right, after clearing the cache the `persist` got detected, but another error occured so I changed the whole question instead of opening another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to save entities [detached](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities) from `EntityManager`. `Workflow`, `Project` entities get marked as `NEW` and get scheduled for insert instead of update. During exploration of the `project->fuel` association of session's `Project` the other `Fuel` entity with non-empty `id` value get found. But it is detached and `id` could not be found in `EntityManager` therefore the exception is raised.

The entities that supposed to have a corresponding row in DB but loaded not by `EntityManager` (unserialized from session in your example) should be [merged](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities) into `EntityManager`. You should merge all `Workflow`, `Project`, `Fuel` instances. The easiest way will be to configure the `workflow->project` and `project->fuel` associations for the cascade merge `cascade: [merge]` and to merge only the session `Workflow`.

```
$manager = $this->getObjectManager();
$sessionObject = $session->get($workflowSessionName);
$manager->merge($sessionObject);
$manager->flush();
```

Note that this will automatically replace entities field values with the ones fetched from the session.

Comment: What you can´t know is following:
1. I have a propery `states` in my `Workflow` class which has a `manyToOne` relation to another class `State`. 
2. In my `editCreateFirstFormPartAction` method you can edit/add all elements of the `states` property. 
3. When add/edit a state in my `editCreateFirstFormPartAction`, after submit the parameter object `$workflow` gets filled with the form values and gets persisted.
4. When submitting the second form gets submitted and the `createEditWorkflowSecondPartAction` gets called, the parameter object  `$workflowSecond` gets filled.

Comment: 5. When then call `$manager->merge($sessionObject);` and `flush` the editing/adding of all states stays mistakenly, I think because Doctrines `UnitOfWork` class holds the states of the previous workflow object. `$workflow` and `$workflowSecond` have the same reference inside Doctrines `UnitOfWork` class. __Thats why I can´t use `merge`!__

Comment: no, the problem is that it is the `oneToMany` association and the owning side here is `State` - it never loaded and never removed therefore

Comment: You should try to configure this relation with `cascade: [merge]` and orphan removal for it http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using redirect to route, a new request is being created to load the second part of the form. At this point the identityMap has been rebuilt and has no reference of the mapping(the long id) for the previously loaded session object (Workflow). Try retrieving the object from database again and setting the properties with session object's values.

PS: There may be a cleaner way to do this which I am not aware of.